Fujitsu Primergy TX1320M4 - additional backplane installation
I‘ve upgraded a Fujitsu Primergy TX1320M4 from four to eight 2.5 HDD by installing an additional backplane using the official upgrade kit.
Both backplanes are connected to a PRAID CP400i. Disks which are inserted into one of the 4 slots of the new backplane are recognized and operate correctly, but show an orange LED. When inserted into the first backplane no orange LED is shown.
The documentation states that after installing an additional backplane, the Chassis ID prom tool must be run to update the chassis eeprom. But I don’t know where to get this tool.
Might this be the reason for the disk orange LED?

PROM could mean programmable read only memory; that's likely to be invoked with some shortcut during system firmware initialization, like BIOS/UEFI setup (or from the UEFI setup, maybe). But, you can also query logs from your controller. Your CP400i is a rebranded MegaRAID SAS, so obtain megacli from Broadcom and see here or here to know how to use it.

Thx. But I don’t think the RAID controller is the problem because I can create logical volumes and so on and everything is working fine.

As supposed, Chassis ID Prom Tool solved the issue by updating the hardware configuration to two backplanes.

The Chassis ID Tool is your way of saying that you like Fujitsu hardware.
5.2.17 Using the Chassis ID Prom Tool
System information must be updated after one of the following tasks:

Front panel module: replacing (with the same type); changing (from front panel module 2.5-inch to front panel on QRL)

HDD/SSD backplane (2.5-inch, 3.5-inch, PCIe): installing; removing; changing (the technology, for example from SAS/SATA to PCIe)

Extension boxes: installing; removing;

Specified expansion cards (for example Retimer, EP5xxi): replacing

Converting the server: from rack model to floorstand model; from floorstand model to rack model


The tool and more information are available to maintenance personnel from the Fujitsu web
pages:
https://partners.ts.fujitsu.com/com/service/ps/Servers/PRIMERGY/

Select your PRIMERGY system from the main area of the page.

From the categories selection, choose Software & Tools Documentation.

In the Tools area click Tools: Chassis-IDProm Tool to download the file (tool-chassis-Idprom-Tool.zip).


https://manuals.ts.fujitsu.com/isc_illustrated_spares/content/TX1320_M4/pdf/tx1320m4-umm-en.pdf

Thx. Don‘t have access to this page yet although registered for their extranet. So you think after running the tool the orange led issue should be solved?
