How to activate backplane 2 in TX2550 M4?
I wanted to expand the Fujitsu TX2550 M4 with another backplane.
But there is a problem.
The server doesn't see it.
I have FUJITSU PRAID CP400i installed on it.
Originally, this server had only one backplane for 4 disks total. Now it has 2 backplanes for 8disks total. Changing cables going from praid to backplane doesn't change anything. So it seems it is not a problem with raid controller.
Operating system on this server is VMWARE ESXi. So, there is no way to install MegaCli permanently. I also can't find a way to run MegaRaid GUI from bios. On old IBM servers it was a lot easier.
Any suggestions will be welcomed.

TX or MX? (headline and body or the question)

Ups. You got me. It should be: TX2550 M4.

You probably need to run the chassis id tool. https://serverfault.com/questions/1159810/fujitsu-primergy-tx1320m4-additional-backplane-installation

Yes that was the answer. Sadly there is no way to download it. I hadto call Fujitsu and pay for support. It works now :)
